# Git without local copy

Tags: git, workflow, local, remote-server

[Edit]

How can I setup/use Git for a workflow without working on files on the local machine.

I would like to avoid a local copy of the whole site and work directly on the remote test server, then commited/deployed to the live server.

Comment: `I usually don't work on a local copy of a web site but directly via (S)FTP on the files in the test site.` Well I guess its time to set up a local development environment.

Comment: Hello, as-is this question is wayyyyy too wide. There's a lot to unpack. We live in a new (like 15-years old, let's call it new nonetheless)  world of DevOps, continuous deployment, hot-deployment, ... You are stuck in the 80's. The 80's were great, don't take it as badly, humanity did great thing with those ways of engineering, don't get me wrong. BUT. But if you want/need to start using the newest methods, you'll need a bit more than change one tool. The whole way of thinking about code evolution have shifted.

Comment: You need a proper development environment; it can be local, it can be on the cloud/could be web-based.... You need an environment where you can code, test and debug . Then, you need a pipeline to package & deploy your software. Then you need environments to deploy to. I suggest you go step by step. Start with the dev environment. Then automatise your packaging & deployment to production. Once ready, create your first non-prod environment you can deploy to using the exact same tools. Read, document yourself; there are quality materials online. Have fun!

Comment: tkausl, YSC: I worked locally in my early years, but it's way too slow for me.

Comment: If it's too slow for you, it's too slow for everybody. Yet millions develop locally. You must be doing something wrong ;)

Comment: YSC: I used to develop locally in my early years. One day by chance I discovered the possibility of editing files directly on the server in WinSCP, I didn't know that possibility before. I develop remote since 10-15 years now, and it's just so fast and efficient. I can only speak for myself, but that's how I meet my responsibilities. I must be doing a few things right too :-)

Comment: "I would like to avoid a local copy of the whole site and work directly on the remote test server"—so install Git there and use it as your local development environment. What's the problem?

Comment: Chris: Thanks, that might be the solution, mg161 wrote the same. Problem could be that I'm not in charge of the Git installation.

Comment: I have no idea why the reworked question is still closed and what I should do to have it reopened. Is it maybe because someone disagrees with my mode of development? Anyway, I received a good answer by 2 nice people, and that's fine.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to a command line on the remote server, you can install git directly on the remote server and push your changes from there to a remote repository.

Comment: I suppose that's the solution. Thanks :-)